# Issues with String length

Tags: java

I am using this piece of code to search through an `ArrayList`. I used the `str.length()` for to read the length of the search field value. The issue is that it throws an "Index out of bounds" exception at the `if(movieArrayList.get(i)` part. I know it has to do with the `.substring(0,stringSize)` because the search I am entering is longer than the shortest title that is in the `ArrayList`. I am not sure how to correct this issue.

```
class SearchListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object[] movieList = movieArrayList.toArray();
        String searchValue = SearchCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        // System.out.println(searchValue);
        if (TelevisionBox.isSelected()) {
            switch (searchValue) {
                case "Title" : {
                    // System.out.println(searchValue);
                    String str = SearchField.getText();
                    int stringSize = str.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < movieArrayList.size(); i++) {
                        // System.out.println(searchValue);
                        if (movieArrayList.get(i).getTitle().substring(0, stringSize).equalsIgnoreCase(str)
                                && str.substring(0, 2).equals("Te")) {
                            System.out.println(str);
                            ResultArea.append(str.toString() + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I am not sure how to correct this issue"* How about not cutting the String and use `startsWith`?

Comment: should be size - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
movieArrayList.get(i).getTitle().substring(0, stringSize)
```

Because the title at `i` could be less that `stringSize`, which comes from `SearchField.getText()`

and also it could come from this line:

```
str.substring(0, 2)
```

Same reason as before, `SearchField.getText().length` could be less than `2`.

You could solve it as Tom suggested with the startWith method.

```
movieArrayList.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase()) &&
str.toLowerCase().startsWith("te")
```

Note that you have toLowerCase the String because startsWith is key sensitive.

Comment: @ForswornDragon np, don't forget to accept the answer please.

Comment: alright now that that was sorted out I am having difficulties with displaying the results from the search bar. I removed the System.out.println(str); since that was for debugging purposes. I am not sure what to plug into ResultArea.append, i know if i put movieArrayList it will just put out all the content in the ArrayList. If i need to ask this as another question let me know.

Comment: @ForswornDragon yes, you need to create a new question since the problem is different now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getting the substring which you are uncertain of the String length, you can use:

- String.contains()

  ```
  //Check if your input string exist in any of your movie names
  ```
- String.matches()

  ```
  //Check if your input string matches any of your movie names
  ```
- String.startsWith()

  ```
  //Check if any of your movie names begins with the input string
  ```

**Example:**

```
if (movieArrayList.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(str))
if (movieArrayList.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().matches(str+".*"))
if (movieArrayList.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(str))
```